# Android - How listener object is not destroyed even after the method is finished?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In android (java), If I declared any variables/objects reference inside the method, it is removed from stack after the method is finished.

But if I register click listener in a method, then how it is invoked even after the method is finished.

Code:

```java
public void init() {
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  }
}):

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "If I declared any variables/objects reference inside the method, it
> is removed from stack after the method is finished."

This is incorrect. If you create any objects, they stay on the *heap* until they're garbage collected. If there are any references to them -- say, a reference to a stored listener -- then they last until those references go away.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken doesn't the ability to reference the object get lost when you exit the scope but the object and functionality it attached to remains? I thought you could only reference it outside of the scope if you gave it some unique id?

Comment: Nope.  If you created an object with `new`, and passed a reference to it elsewhere -- e.g. passing it to `setOnClickListener` -- then that object stays around as long as that somewhere else retains a reference to it, with no extra work.

Comment: Sorry that's not what I meant. I meant that once you leave the scope you can no longer interact with it in the sense of deleting it. I thought that if you want to delete it after creating with ```new``` that you have to do so in the same scope?

Comment: There's no such thing as deleting an object in Java; all you can do is stop referencing it.